# .htaccess redirect from URL with numeric parameter to URL with text parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having to move an old custom built website to a newer WordPress site.

On the old site, the URL is https://www.example.net/index.php?product=1234567890 and I need to redirect to https://www.example.net/product_name

Each product on the old site is a number parameter, and need to redirect to text on the new site.

So I figure I'll need a separate line in the .htaccess to accomplish this, but I don't know enough .htaccess.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that numeric ID a static number, so the only ID you want to redirect, or are there multiple such IDs? If there are multiple, how should a configuration know which product name to chose for which ID?

Comment: There are multiple IDs, and the configuration is manually entered for each. It's only about 25 products, so I used RewriteCond & RewriteRule for each, as below and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, as `RewriteCond` is like an If statement and `RewriteRule` is like a Then statement.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)product=1314271738($|&)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /product_name? [L,R=301]
```

Very cool!